# Line Chart - Y Axis value not showing in tooltip

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Hi I am using Angular NVD3 line chart. I am getting decimal value for Y Axis. In tickFormat of Y axis, I am changing it to integer format.

Now, the Y axis value in the tooltip not showing up. if the value is integer then only it's showing up.

I tried to use tooltip valueFormatter like below in my chart option -

```
tooltip: {
            valueFormatter: function (d, i){
                return d3.format('.02f')(val);
            }
        }
```

but it's not getting called. Any idea how to show value in tooltip if the tickFormat is different than value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by using below option..

```
interactiveLayer: {
            tooltip: {
                valueFormatter:  function (d, i){
                  return d3.format('.02f')(val);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not sure why there are two tooltip options. one inside interactiveLayer and another outside. it's pretty confusing. Anyways, it worked for me.